# When trying to build Halide on Linux system with llvm-10.0 on release/10.x and master branches, facing the below issue

Tags: clang, llvm, halide

```
[ 53%] Linking CXX executable test_function_dag
/bin/ld: ../../libHalide.so.10.0.0: undefined reference to `typeinfo for llvm::SectionMemoryManager'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/autoschedulers/adams2019/CMakeFiles/test_function_dag.dir/build.make:134: src/autoschedulers/adams2019/test_function_dag] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2328: src/autoschedulers/adams2019/CMakeFiles/test_function_dag.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:182: all] Error 2
```

I'm using pre-built LLVM binaries and below cmake command to configure

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_DIR=/home/harry/llvm/lib/cmake/llvm ../
```

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you build LLVM and how did you configure Halide? It looks like you might be trying to use LLVM out of a build tree, rather than an install tree.

Comment: I am using the pre-built binaries for LLVM.

Comment: Whose pre-built binaries? Your distro's? Which distro? From the LLVM website?

Comment: You should post the command you used to configure Halide so we can try to repro.

Comment: ok sure, i've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned Halide from `release/10.x`, and compiled against the LLVM 10.0.0 binaries [obtained here](https://releases.llvm.org/download.html#10.0.0). On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I had to also `apt install libtinfo5` because these binaries are built against old system libraries.

I noticed that the official binaries are not built with RTTI enabled (ugh) and was able to repro and fix. There's a bug in `dependencies/llvm/CMakeLists.txt`. Find the line that reads:

```
$<$<COMPILE_LANG_AND_ID:CXX,GCC,Clang,AppleClang>:-fno-rtti>)
```

and change `GCC` to `GNU`. We don't test with non-RTTI LLVM, which is why this wasn't caught.

Comment: I opened an issue. Thanks for finding this! https://github.com/halide/Halide/issues/5418

Comment: Thank you, I am able to build it now.

Comment: This fix is now in upstream Halide and has been backported to the `release/10.x` branch. It will be available in the 10.0.1 release.